# What is meant by "Anything that challenges Zalem"?

Tags: alita-battle-angel

In [*Alita Battle Angel* (2019)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alita:_Battle_Angel), Hugo shows Zapan to Alita:

> Hugo: He's a bounty hunter. Named Zapan. Scanning for his mark. I
>   wouldn't wanna be that guy.
>
> ALITA: Look at that sword.
>
> Hugo: All guns are outlawed in Iron City. Punishable by death.
>   **Anything that challenges Zalem**.

What is meant by "Anything that challenges Zalem"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He means that anything that potentially challenges the authority or security of Zalem (the city floating overhead) is banned.

This includes guns but also presumably explosives and rockets bigger than a firework, etc. Small rockets and chain-linked weapons seem to be tolerated when used by hunters and robot derby builders.

In the [comics](https://battleangel.fandom.com/wiki/Battle_10) we see that airplanes and hot air balloons (basically anything that can be used to get up to Zalem) are also strictly forbidden as are certain classes of Battle Angel robot bodies.